# WinInet ftp connection error 123

Tags: c++, winapi, ftp, wininet

I'm trying to connect to my ftp server via C++/WinInet, but I keep receiving error 123 (ERROR_INVALID_NAME). Google research says that this error is caused by wrong server address, but my address is valid, same as my username and password. Here's my code:

```
void FileSubmit(LPCWSTR addr, LPCWSTR login, LPCWSTR pass, LPCWSTR pcFile, LPCWSTR ftpFile)
{
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (hInternet == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Connecting to :"<<(char*)login<<" @ "<<(char*)addr<<", to upload file from PC: "<<(char*)pcFile<<" as "<<(char*)ftpFile<<endl;
        hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, addr, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, 
                    login, pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, NULL, NULL);
        if (hFtpSession == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"FTPSESSION ERROR!\n";
            cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"hFTPsession successfull!\n";
            if (!FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, pcFile, ftpFile, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
            {
                cout << "Error: " << GetLastError();
            }
            else
                cout<<"FILE "<<(char*)pcFile<<" HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED AS "<<(char*)ftpFile<<"!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it like:

```
FileSubmit((LPCWSTR)"ftp.ibieda.cba.pl",(LPCWSTR)"login",
               (LPCWSTR)"pass",(LPCWSTR)"C:\\file.txt",(LPCWSTR)"\\file.txt");
```

can anybody help and tell me why is InternetConnect returning 123 (ERROR_INVALID_NAME) ?

Comment: "ftp.server.x" doesn't sound like a valid domain name to me.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is just example.

Comment: What says debugger? Probably your retyping from char string to LPCWSTR is root of all evil. Refactor your code and try again.

Comment: @Xearinox yeah, using L"address" instead of (LPCWSTR)"address" worked! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type-casting from `const char*` to `const wchar*` is wrong. Pass wide string literals (for example, `L"ftp.ibieda.cpl.pl"`) or use the `MultiByteToWideChar()` function.

Answer (score -2):

I had error 123 on InternetConnect using a program that had worked well in the past. My issue was the new project i created was set up to use UNICODE. Changed this and it all worked again.